# here maps - showing places through entire route

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, maps, here-api

I am facing one problem in HERE corridor api. If I search for long route and there are so many restaurants at one place on route, then it gives max of 1000 records at the same place.

So is there any way that I can get maximum of say 10 records at each place, so that I can get places all over the route?

I have tried width of the route with the category filter set as 'restaurant', now the problem with this is when we search for longer distances there are just too many records for restaurants and the response only returns all the restaurants around the source only and not all along the way till the destination.
I understand that this could be a practical limitation given the number of records for a given category, but would like to know if there are any workarounds at all for this problem.

Basically, I want to get places all over the route.

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer the link below
https://places.cit.api.here.com/places/v1/browse/by-corridor?route=%5B18.9386%2C72.8242%7C15.48%2C73.8061%5D%3Bw%3D10000&cat=petrol-station&size=500&app_id={app_id}&app_code={app_code}

do not forget to add your app id and code, sorry I cannot comment hence posted it here.

Comment: I have tried this already, m getting the results but not all the way of route.

Comment: To confirm you are using the size attribute available in the Corridor request but still don't get result only around the source point ? Maybe try reducing the width of the route corridor ?

Comment: hey thnx for the reply. Is this an only way to fix this by reducing width?